# How to preserve cascading dropdownlist items after httppost if form has invalid ModelState

Tags: c#, jquery, model-view-controller, drop-down-menu, asp.net-mvc-5

I have three dropdown (cascaded) in a View. First dropdown elements come from the ViewModel. I'm populating 2nd dropdown elements when 1st dropdown changes. and same for the 3rd dropdown. Classic cascading dropdownlist example you can find on anywhere (ex: http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/4d9083/creating-simple-cascading-dropdownlist-in-mvc-4-using-razor/ )

Problem occurs when user submits the form. If ModelState is invalid, 2nd and 3rd dropdown loses their items and 1st dropdown conserves its state. I understand why they behave like that but can't figure it out how to populate them again with the users selected values.

### Scenario

1. User request `/Country/Index`
2. After `page loaded`, user selects `CountryId DropDownList`

   - Send `Country Id` to method and if result is not null, load `StateId DropDownList`.
3. Do not fill `PostalCode Textbox` and submit form.
4. Examine that `CountryId DropDownlist` is filled and selected but `StateId ropdownlist` is empty.
5. Cry

### View

```
//HTML Code
//...

@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.CountryId, ViewBag.Country as IEnumerable<SelectListItem>, "Select Country")
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.StateId, new SelectList(string.Empty, "Value", "Text"), "Select State")
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.CityId, new SelectList(string.Empty, "Value", "Text"), "Select City")
@Html.TextBoxFor(m=> m.PostalCode)

<script type="text/javascript">
var countryDDL = $("#CountryId");
countryDDL.change(function () {
                $.ajax({
                    type: 'POST',
                    url: '@Url.Action("LoadStateList")',
                    dataType: 'json',
                    data: { countryId: countryDDL.val() },
                    success: function myfunction(states) {
                        $("#StateId").empty();
                        $.each(states, function (i, state) {
                            $("#StateId").append('<option value="' + state.Value + '">' + state.Text + '</option>');
                        }); }
                   });
                   return false;
                });

//Code for 2nd (state) dropdownlist.change() method.
//...
</script>
```

### Controller

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    ViewBag.CountryList = LoadCountryList();
    return View();
}

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Index(CountryViewModel cvm)
{
    if(ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        //Save or do whatever you want
    }

    ViewBag.CountryList = LoadCountryList();
    return View();
}
```

### View Model

```
public class CountryViewModel
{
    public int CountryId {get;set;}
    public int StateId {get;set;}
    public int CityId {get;set;}

    [Required]
    public string PostalCode {get;set;}
}
```

Comment: Pass the model back to the view again (in the invalid state it was posted), and when rendering out the `select` make sure the selected item has the id they selected prior to submitting it to the server.

Comment: You mean get states with CountryId in HttpPost method again and send back to view? If so, this means i need to send StateList with initial value in ViewBag.StateList and change the StateDDL code like CountryDDL which uses ViewBag.StateList? Reasonable.

Comment: I think you might be overthinking this (or I'm missing something fundamental). Don't you just need to pass `cvm` into `View()`?

Comment: Look at the code in [this DotNetFiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/JofdB8) - in particular the controller code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The actual select options are not posted (nor should they be). Therefore, when you get to the post action, your select list is empty. The solution? Simply repopulate it the same as you would in your get action. Granted, here, you're not populating those in the get action, but rather retrieving them via AJAX. You could technically do it the same way on post, if you wanted. You'd just have to run the AJAX calls on page load to refetch the select lists. However, it would be much better at this point to just do it in your post action.

Comment: Populating in the controller looks like a better way. I'm an old ASP.NET developer and populating dropdownlists(and other controls because of mvc is stateless ) everytime just bothers me but there is no other way ha! Perhaps i can store ddl items in a Session and don't query the database everytime?

Comment: That's the hidden danger of Web Forms that's I've always complained about: the fact that it hides what's going on behind the scenes from the developer. Repopulating must always be done, Web Forms or MVC. Only, in MVC, you're responsible for it rather than Microsoft deciding how it should be done for you.

Comment: But this overload the database. Mostly EntityFramework is using and making queries over and over again and this is a little bit annoying. May be you can say _"Entity Framework and SQL can handle those queries, technology is improved"_. What is your opinion about keeping them in session?

Comment: If you're doing sessions properly, you still hit the database. However, it hardly "overloads" the database to repopulate the select list items. First, Entity Framework does employ query-caching, so it's possible it won't even hit the database again. Second, unless you're doing some kind of crazy query, it will be quick. Databases are designed to query data quickly and efficiently unless you do things that are deliberately inefficient and slow. A quick bit of profiling can point out any potential issues.

Comment: Long and short, if you've got a good, optimized query, and that *alone* is able to overload your database, then you have some serious problems that need to be fixed. Maybe the database needs more resources. Regardless, if you're *really* concerned, you can use the built-in memory caching ASP.NET provides to cache the results of the query for some period of time and then first attempt to pull the items from cache before using EF. That said, there's probably a hundred different areas of your application that would deserve optimization before you got to something like this.

Comment: Entity Framework Caching and Memory Caching are 2 research keywords for me :) Thanks for your help. I was able to answer questions in my head.

Comment: I have the same problem. After submitting the form, the second dropdown list turns empty. How do you repopulate the second dropdown again? Thanks